# Why am I getting "SessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint is not set." even though I have the finger print in the script

Tags: powershell, ssh, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I am using SFTP to transfer files to a remote server but I keep getting

> SessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint is not set.

I referenced this documentation from WinSCP [WinSCP .NET Assembly and COM Library](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library)

What am I doing wrong? See script below:

```
try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
    Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
        Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
        HostName = "psftp-nesam.ms.com"
        UserName = "test"
        Password = "MSR4sssssnd5"
        SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 1024 +3t0xkOMWqfA7IaH0itjW/w7FQN+EtVyLDMTXk+D300=
    ssh-rsa 1024 23:6f:82:11:ec:b1:1a:82:95:1b:ed:7e:96:24:d0:11"
    }

    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

    try
    {
        # Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        # Upload files
        $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
        $transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary

        $transferResult =
            $session.PutFiles("E:\CMBPAID\BPAID0224_122700.csv", "/NESAMSCARIMED", $False, $transferOptions)

        # Throw on any error
        $transferResult.Check()

        # Print results
        foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
        {
            Write-Host "Upload of $($transfer.FileName) succeeded"
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }

    exit 0
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your code I'm getting a different error message (but it can be a root cause of your error message):

> The value supplied is not valid, or the property is read-only. Change the value, and then try again.

What is correct, as your syntax of a `SshHostKeyFingerprint` value is wrong.

If you want to specify multiple alternative fingerprints, separate them by a semicolon, not a new-line:

```
SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 1024 +3t0xkOMWqfA7IaH0itjW/w7FQN+EtVyLDMTXk+D300=;ssh-rsa 1024 23:6f:82:11:ec:b1:1a:82:95:1b:ed:7e:96:24:d0:11"
```

With this change, your code works for me.

Answer (score 5):

The easy way to get a correct key is to run the WinSCP application, login to the SFTP server you want to access, then select from drop down menu at top "Sessions->Generate Session URL/Code...".  This will display a nice dialog box with different ways to write code to connect to this session.  The tab ".NET assembly code" has all the code you need to make the same connection, including the "SshHostKeyFingerprint".